# ASP.NET MVC Editor templates empty string for name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvc-editor-templates

In some editor templates (e. g., default editor template for object) editors are rendered by property name: `Html.Editor(prop.PropertyName)`. But in some other editor templates I see empty string is used for name: `Html.Editor("")` Why? And how does it work?

Comment: `Html.Editor` isn't a valid helper method, you mean `Html.EditorFor`.

Answer (score 0):

`Html.Editor()` takes in a string input, which then becomes an **id** and the **name** property of the editor textbox created.

For example, if I use some thing like this

```
<p>
Editor 1 : @Html.Editor("firstName")
</p>
```

this will be rendered as

```
<p>
Editor 1 : <input type="text" value="" name="firstName" id="firstName" class="text-box single-line">
</p>
```

this is how, Html.Editor is used.

But if you use something like this, (which you have)

```
<p>
Editor 2 : @Html.Editor("")
</p>
```

this will render like this

```
<p>
Editor 2 : 
</p>
```

Hope this answers your quesion.